# $JAVA_HOME path not sourced correctly in ~/bash_profile at login

Tags: java, linux, bash, centos, java-home

Upon logging into my CentOS 7 VM, my $JAVA_HOME is always set to :
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-11.b12.el7.x86_64/jre`, which is incorrect.

My ~/.bash_profile reads:

```
#  .bash_profile

#  Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre
export JAVA_HOME

PYCHARM_HOME=/opt/pycharm-community-2017.2.3/
export PYCHARM_HOME

ECLIPSE_HOME=/opt/eclipse
export ECLIPSE_HOME

export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PYCHARM_HOME/bin:$ECLIPSE_HOME

export PATH
```

Sourcing .bash_profile each time I open a new terminal appears to correct the issue, but why is my $JAVA_HOME path defaulting to an old version on startup and not being set to the directory specified in .bash_profile?

Comment: how did u login to the vm? ssh?

Comment: I'm logged in locally using the VM image installed on my laptop in VMWare Workstation 12.

Comment: Seems like your `.bash_profile` is not being sourced upon login.  Check your login shell.

Answer (score 1):

> Sourcing .bash_profile each time I open a new terminal appears to
>   correct the issue, but why is my $JAVA_HOME path defaulting to an old
>   version on startup and not being set to the directory specified in
>   .bash_profile?

You need to logout from current user and login again so environment variables changes take place.

**May be useful**

In Bash:

- Bash as login shell will load `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` in the order.
- Bash as non-login interactive shell will load `~/.bashrc`

**Environment :**

- Use `/etc/environment` to permanently system wide (all users, all processes)  set environmental variables for all users.

  `/etc/environment` is a system-wide configuration file, which means it is used by all users. It is owned by root though, so you need to be an admin user and use sudo to modify it.

  Suppose if you set `foo="bar"` variable `foo` will be accessible from all the user sessions. To test the variable output first source it

  `source /etc/environment`
- `~/.profile` is one of your own user's personal shell initialization scripts. Every user has one and can edit their file without affecting others.
- `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` are the global initialization scripts that are equivalent to `~/.profile` for each user. The global scripts get executed before the user-specific scripts though; and the main `/etc/profile` executes all the `*.sh` scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` just before it exits.

Also note,

- The `/etc/environment` file sets the variable system wide for every user on login.
- Commands in the `bash_profile` are is executed if the bash shell is opened by any user. So the variables would not be set unless a bash shell is opened at least one time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `ps` in the interactive shell to make sure you're in `bash`.
2. Try `bash -l` after login and see if it fixes your problem.
3. Add `set -x` before `JAVA_HOME=...` to check if there's something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**It worked for me!**

In my case, The follwing caused the error:

`export JAVA_HOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home`

The error was that there were **spaces before and after the `=`** . **The error disappeared after those spaces were removed.**

So the correct command is as follows:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home`