# how to update JAVA_HOME in bashrc file

Tags: java, linux, environment-variables

I am getting problem in bashrc file.After update in JAVA_HOME, I ran source bashrc but still it is pointing java-1.8.0 version.Please help me out.
new changes in bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/satyajit/project/packages/jdk1.7.0_80 
export JRE_HOME=/home/satyajit/project/packages/jdk1.7.0_80/jre 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

When I ran source bashrc o/p:

```
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-3.b16.el6_9.x86_64: is a directory
```

Comment: If you're accessing a login shell, try editing `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: echo your `$PATH` here.

Comment: Hi mena ... I edit .bash_profile but still I am facing same issue

Comment: Man, you made no effort at all. [$JAVA_HOME resets after every terminal login](https://askubuntu.com/q/725697), [$JAVA_HOME path not sourced correctly in ~/bash_profile at login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46679363/608639), [How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24641536/608639), [How to set environment variable JAVA_HOME that will be saved on exit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42032/56041), [bash or bash_profile JAVA_HOME permanent export](https://superuser.com/q/611606/173513), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JAVA\_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

Answer (score 0):

remove ":$PATH" from the path
example: export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin

After updated class path in .bashrc execute the command "source .bashrc" from terminal or restart the system

Comment: Bad idea. That way you can't run regular commands like `ls` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this!It worked for me

```
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

export JAVA_HOME=<path to java file>
export JAVA_HOME=/home/janakan/Applications/jdk1.8.0_241
```

Comment: What's the difference? You just `$PATH` in the front?

Comment: I guess it   is the syntax that we need to use in bashrc file .  Check this link                                          https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work .